# Using a old site when create a new PrestaShop-project

Tags: installation, prestashop

I have a client that want to use a PrestaShop system. But he don't want to close the old site before the new is designed and done to use. What should I do if I don't want to reinstall etc?

Which is the easiest way to do this?

What I want to do is do design and develop the end product at the server so I dont spend hours of designing and developing to get to a point where I can't use it because i installed the system on a demo-server.

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Could you elaborate a bit more on your actual problem ?

Comment: Yes- I updated my post!

Comment: This question is not about Prestashop, but about a web site update procedure. You can install your CMS at the live server, but use another directory, another subdomain and make a new database. So you'll be sure both demo and live sites share the same environment.

Comment: Even if the other system is not a PrestaShop-system?